# jscrollpane dragging outside frame

Tags: frame, jscrollpane

I replaced normal scroll bars with Jscrollpane (see http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com). Very nice. But I am using a screen with two frames. When I'm dragging the scroll bar in the left frame and accidentally leave this frame (mouse enters right frame), the dragging is halted. This is very user-unfriendly (users need to stay on the left side of the frame border) and does not happen with normal scrollbars. 
Anyone know how to be able to keep dragging a Jscrollpane whilst entering another frame?